# Very slow join of the small table to the big one

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I needed to add one more column to already existing one (~6M rows).

Unfortunately, I cannot modify the table.

So, I created another one, which contains only two columns: the first (DI_key) corresponds to the primary key of the large table (ID_key) and the second (int(11)) corresponds to the property I want to keep in the database.

For the moment the second table contains only ~250 rows, but when I LEFT JOIN it ON (DI_key = ID_key) my requests to the bigger table are ~ 1000 times slower!

Adding indexes on the small table doesn't solve the problem.

Any suggestions would be welcome...

Unfortunately, I'm working on the very old infrastructure - MySQL 5.1

**Technical infos:**

```
--
-- Structure de la table `line`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `line` (
  `ID_line` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LISOCI` char(2) DEFAULT '02',
  `LICLIE` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `LIADLIV` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LICMD` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LICMDM` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `LILIG` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LIARTI` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `LIDES1` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `LIDES2` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `LIQTE1` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE2` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE3` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE4` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE5` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE6` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE7` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE8` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE9` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE10` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE11` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LIQTE12` float DEFAULT '0',
  `LICOMMENT` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT1` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT2` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT3` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT4` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT5` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT6` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT7` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT8` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT9` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT10` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT11` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LICMT12` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `LIUNIV` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `LILIBQTE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LIQNIF` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LIDATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `LIPRIX` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LIPVCONSO` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LITOTAL` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LIPRV` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `LILOGON` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `LIADRIP` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `LISESSION` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `LIGRATUIT` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_line`),
  KEY `I1` (`LISOCI`,`LICLIE`,`LICMD`,`LILIG`),
  KEY `I2` (`LISOCI`,`LICLIE`,`LICMD`,`LISESSION`,`LILIG`),
  KEY `L12` (`LICMDM`,`LILIG`),
  KEY `LICMD` (`LICMD`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7185054 ;

--
-- Structure de la table `line_info`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `line_info` (
  `DI_line` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `LICLIES` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`DI_line`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "line":

```
+------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows    | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time          | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| line | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    | 6339101 |            179 |  1135581592 | 281474976710655 |    429571072 |      3356 |        7185054 | 2023-01-27 09:31:29 | 2023-02-06 14:49:08 | 2023-01-27 09:34:49 | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "line_info":

```
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name      | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length  | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| line_info | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |  239 |             13 |        3107 | 3659174697238527 |         6144 |         0 |           NULL | 2023-02-07 09:50:45 | 2023-02-07 09:50:45 | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-----------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

EXPLAIN SELECT:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `line`.*, `line_info`.`LICLIES` 
FROM `line` 
LEFT JOIN `line_info` ON DI_line = ID_line 
WHERE (LISOCI LIKE '02') 
AND (LICLIE IN ('44', '55') OR LICLIES IN ('44', '55')) 
AND LICMD = 0 
AND LICMDM = '' 
AND LILOGON = 'WWW' 
AND LIDATE >= '2022-12-02 16:53:56'
```

Result:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+--------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref          | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+--------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | line      | ref    | I1,I2,L12,LICMD | L12     | 34      | const        | 56594 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | line_info | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY | 8       | line.ID_line |     1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+--------------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please post the complete query that is taking so long AND for every table involved TEXT results of, A) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; and SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "tbl_name";  and EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query);  for analysis

Comment: Sounds like the new table is missing `PRIMARY KEY(DI_key).  (And I need the stuff Wilson asked for.)

Comment: I've just added the technical info you requested.